# Настройка ListView внутри скролинга

Tags: java, android, android-scrollview

Есть список комментариев под шапкой, они должны лежать в ScrollView и занимать все пространство ниже шапки.  Также под шапкой  есть еще одна шапка, но меньше и она должна скролится вместе со списком комментариев!!!

Но почему-то комментарии не занимают все свободное место и подшапка не прокручивается.

Вот мой код:

**Лейаут элемента комментария:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorLight"

        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/coment_avatar_round"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/circle_radius"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/circle_radius"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_midle_size"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:padding="@dimen/inner_padding"
            android:text="N"
            />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/coment_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/coment_avatar_round"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="@dimen/inner_padding"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:text="coment"
             />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

**Класс ListFragment для этого лейаута**

```
public class ComentsViewFragment extends ListFragment {

        ArrayList<ComentInflater> comentInflaters = new ArrayList<>();
        String text = "vvvvvvvvvvvvvvv" +
                "vvvvvvvvvvvv" +
                "vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv" +
                "vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv " +
                "vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv" +
                "vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv  gggggggggggggg" +
                " gggggggggggggg " +
                "gggggggggggggg" ;


        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            comentInflaters.add(new ComentInflater("#ff3d00", "A", text));
            comentInflaters.add(new ComentInflater("#ff3d00",  "V", text));
            comentInflaters.add(new ComentInflater("#ff3d00", "D" , text));
            comentInflaters.add(new ComentInflater("#ff3d00", "O" , text));
            comentInflaters.add(new ComentInflater("#ff3d00", "M" , text));
            comentInflaters.add(new ComentInflater("#ff3d00", "K" , text));
            comentInflaters.add(new ComentInflater("#ff3d00", "L" , text));

            ComentAdapter comentAdapter = new ComentAdapter(comentInflaters);

            setListAdapter(comentAdapter);

        }



        private class ComentAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ComentInflater>{

            public ComentAdapter(ArrayList<ComentInflater> coment){
                super(getActivity(), 0, coment);
            }


            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                if (convertView == null){
                    convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.coments_layout, null);
                }

                ComentInflater c = getItem(position);

                Button avatarButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.coment_avatar_round);
                avatarButton.setText(c.getLetter());

                TextView textComent = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.coment_text);

                textComent.setText(c.getText());


                return convertView;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Потом я помещаю этот фрагмент на главное активити:**

***лейаут активити***

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
            />

        <ScrollView

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/sub_el"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"/>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/test_croll_conteiner"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

**Класс активности:**

```
public class TestScroll extends FragmentActivity {




      @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.test_scroll_activity);

            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.test_croll_conteiner, new ComentsViewFragment()) ;
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();

        }
    }
```

**В результате комментарии прокручиваются, но занимают место равное одному комментарию, то есть не заполняют весе свободное пространство! А подшапка не прокручивается вообще !!**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Голубое - это шапка, под ней "подшапка", под ней мой лист, а серая область (всю эту серуюю область должен занимать лист)это скроинг !

**Как это исправить ?? Или сделать правильно ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Опираясь на ответ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29041079/listfragment-inside-a-scrollview-android

попробуйте засунуть шапку отдельным View, засовывать лучше так
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6205967/5892568

Comment: Было бы хорошо, если бы помимо ссылок привели, кратко, инормацию из них. Ибо ссылки могут помереть и не все анг. знают.